# Replace em apenas 1 caracter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

estou tentando fazer o replace do seguinte exemplo:

> "Eu $ tenho $2 muito $$dinheiro$$"

Nesse cenário gostaria de substituir apenas os **"$"** que não estão duplicados como **"$$"**, ficando a frase a seguir:

> "Eu tenho 2 muito $dinheiro$"

já tentei utilizar o **str.Replace("$", "")**, mas ele substitui todos os "$"

Comment: Tem algumas questões que não estão claras na pergunta: Haverão outros casos de ocorrências múltiplas do `"$"`? O "$$" é uma sequencia de escape? Como seriam feitas as substituições caso a frase fosse `"Eu $ tenho $$2 muito $$$dinheiro$$$$"`? Veja um exemplo simples sem o uso de regex https://ideone.com/KbJ8Ni

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Acredito que para fazer isso tu vai precisar criar uma expressão regular.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string str = "Eu $ tenho $2 muito $$dinheiro$$";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\$(?!\$)", "");
```

Comment: Expressão regular em C# funciona normalmente como em outras linguagens, estou tentando montar uma a algumas horas, mas até o momento nada eficaz

Comment: Quase lá, agora eu preciso apenas substituir os primeiros "$" da palavra " $$dinheiro$$", para ficar assim "$$dinheiro$$"

Comment: Mas o que ele propôs faz exatamente o que você especificou na pergunta: https://regex101.com/r/JdyTqs/1

Comment: É que eu não tinha visto que tinha que tirar do $$dinheiro$$ também, ai editei a resposta ^^